# How to determine number of decimals on a double?

Tags: java, decimalformat

This question has been asked severally but I have specifications that have never been mentioned in previously asked questions.

I want to know how many numbers are there after a decimal place including the last ZEROs.

I have tried this:

```
double d= user_input;
String text =Double.toString(Math.abs(d));
int integerPlaces =text.indexOf('.');
int decimalPlaces =text.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
```

Where **user_input** is any value a user can put.

It is working well for example `2.384` is showing `3` decimals, that's correct.

But when the user puts: `2.38400`  it is still showing `3` decimals ignoring the zeros. I want to also count those zeros to get the result as `5`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to fix this at the point when you get the text from the user. After you've converted it to `double` you can't do that

Comment: You cannot get `user_input` as double. Receive it as a string. When You cast "1.10" on double it automatically will be `1.1`

Comment: I am not receiving it as double. Its text, and I am converting it to string then to double.

Comment: Anyway, if counting zeros on a double seems impossible,  how if I calculate number of values after the decimal before i convert it to double? How can i do that?

Comment: yes you are receiving it as a double: `double d= user_input;`

Comment: The 0s at the ends of a decimal number are infinite. By convention they are ignored. There is no way to know the number of 0s a tthe end of a double because there are none

Comment: If the number is a `double` and the precision exceeds 15 then there is no way to find this.  If it is a `String` then what is the issue?

Comment: A `double` is internally represented in binary, not decimal, so it doesn’t make sense to ask how many decimals it has got. Or put in a different way, it hasn’t got any.

Comment: There is no difference between 2.384 and 2.38400: they're the same double value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String text = "34.0003400";

 int noOfDecimalPlaces = text.length() - text.indexOf(".") - 1;
```

### update

```
String text = "3454";
        int noOfDecimalPlaces;
        if (text.indexOf(".") != -1) {
            noOfDecimalPlaces = text.length() - text.indexOf(".") - 1;
        } else {
            noOfDecimalPlaces = 0;
        }
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, it is giving me correct result, however when the user input is integer only like: 45 I am getting number of decimals as 2 yet there is not decimal places. It is working well when it is a decimal only like: 45.00 i get result as 2 decimals. Can you adjust a bit to accommodate if there is no decimals?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String text = YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.getText().toString().trim();


String[] arr = text.split("\\.");

int noOfDecimalPlaces = arr[1].length();
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: This doesn't *behave* the way you think it does. The above code will split the `String` on each character and is sort of equivalent to `toCharArray`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I did split the array on `.`. Then How will it become similar to `toCharArray()`?

Comment: `split` argument is a regex. A dot as a regex is not the same as a dot in a plain string

Comment: @jhamon Okay...Does this work? `char[] arr = text.split("\\.");`

Comment: This still does not work, `arr[1]` is a `char`, and obviously it has no `length()` method.